# How can I correctly sort an index (wbs)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Anyone have an idea how to sort the records according to their index number (wbscode)

If I use ORDER BY after 1.1.9 it does not continue 1.1.10 changes to 1.2
I can't find a correct way to do a consecutive order of this.

someone knows a way to do it correctly ie

 1

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.1.3

1.1.4

1.1.5

1.1.6

1.1.7

1.1.8

1.1.9

1.1.10

1.1.11

1.2

1.2.1

2

.....
**SELECT wbs FROM houses  ORBER BY wbs**   :(
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the datatype `hierarchyid`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([WBSCode] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1')
,('1.1.1')
,('1.1.2')
,('1.1.3')
,('1.1.4')
,('1.1.5')
,('1.1.6')
,('1.1.7')
,('1.1.8')
,('1.1.9')
,('1.1.10')
,('1.1.11')
,('1.2')
,('1.2.1')
,('2')
 
Select * 
 from @YourTable
 order by convert(hierarchyID,'/'+replace(WBSCode,'.','/')+'/')
```

**Results**

```
WBSCode
1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.4
1.1.5
1.1.6
1.1.7
1.1.8
1.1.9
1.1.10
1.1.11
1.2
1.2.1
2
```